# Paros is not launching

Tags: java, windows-7-x64, parosproxy

OS: Windows7 64-bit
Java: jdk1.8.0_05

I have downloaded "paros-3.2.13-win.exe" and installed successfully. When I double-click desktop icon "Paros 3.2.13" it was not launched. The following screen was shown:
[image]

Please help me to find out the problem of running Paros proxy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paros hasnt been updated for many years.
You should try OWASP ZAP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ZAP
Its a fork of Paros that is very actively maintained.

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)

Comment: Yes, OWASP ZAP is a nice tool.